# Is there a predefined schema type to store UNIX timestamp in realm react-native?

Tags: react-native, realm

I was looking into the schema types defined by realm and I see date as an option but I don't prefer saving date formats. Rather I feel UNIX `timestamps` are more reliable & universal.

Is there a default schema type in realm for this? or will I have to store it as int or long?

Also I researched a bit but could not find a document from where I can see all possible schema types supported by realm react-native in model definition. Can anyone cite a source? (I wanted to be assured that storing boolean was a possibility)

Comment: Supported types: Realm supports the following basic types: `bool, int, float, double, string, data, and date`.  **date properties map to Date** is that what you need? Internally it's stored as an "integer" in Realm (which is long)

Comment: Ok, so with `date` can I apply hooks like `default: current_timestamp` & `on update : current_timestamp` like we do with SQL or will I have to handle this while passing values in `write()`?

Comment: Most likely passing values in `write()`.

Comment: Ok thanks. And I believe similar for auto increment as well. No special hook to set auto increment. Will have to be managed through code, correct?

Comment: Auto-increment cannot be guaranteed in a distributed environment, so Realm never planned to supported it, I think.